# How to recompile libc to use soft float?

Tags: linux, floating-point, mips, libc

Libc had to be upgraded (via apt-get) for a certain package.  That package is no longer needed, and by upgrading libc through apt-get I cannot build certain other programs from source any more.  I need to recompile libc to use soft float instead of hard float so I can once again compile the programs I need.

Right now I get a warning like so:

> Warning: /usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS) uses hard float, foobar uses soft float

...and running the compiled foobar will result in the error:

> Floating point exception

The system itself is on a MIPS64 architecture.  Before upgrading libc through apt-get, these programs compiled and ran successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recompiling libc is difficult. Your best bet is to find a precompiled 64 bit soft float libc online, or restore your original from backup. Take a look at the free [CodeSourcery Lite](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/) MIPS toolchain, which includes many different libc versions.

Comment: I don't see anything here, just looks like the support portal for their product?

Comment: I think it would ordinarily be preferable to obtain precompiled system libraries from the packages of the distribution installed, rather than from a toolchain contributor, even if the later has something allegedly compatible, unless you have a very specific reason to believe that the distribution's version is inferior.

Comment: I agree, but the OP seems to be having trouble getting the libraries from the distribution's source, so this is another option to try.

Comment: The difficulty in finding the precompiled libraries from the packages of the distro is that they don't appear to exist for my architecture.  Thank you for the updated link, I will look in to it shortly.